# Two window.location not working togeather

Tags: javascript, function, url, query-string

I have two functions what sets a `window.location.href` tag in the url, but when I set the first one and then select the other one, the first one disappears. So how should I do? These functions are in a form that makes a selection of 1. project name and 2. package. And then you submit the form (php) the fields adds to the database.

```
function jsFunction(){
    var myselect = document.getElementById("projektnamn");
    window.location.href = "?projektnamn=" + myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value;
}

function services(){
    var select = document.getElementById("paket");
    window.location.href = "?paket=" + select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
domain.com?projektnamn=Something?paket=Something
```

What I get today is:

```
domain.com?projektnamn=Something
```

Or I get:

```
domain.com?paket=Something
```

Comment: Hi, could you clarify what you expect to happen here? There will always be one current value for that variable, and one current URL the user is looking at. Did you want the URLs to be combined in some way?

Comment: When you set one and than the other it disappears? You are replacing the url with a string. Are you expecting it to remember `projektnamn` and `paket`?

Comment: So you need to code something to build the url with both

Comment: Yes I need ta have a script that build the url without dropping the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the link in a variable

```
let query = "";
function jsFunction(){
  var myselect = document.getElementById("projektnamn");
  query += "?projektnamn=" + myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value;
}

function services(){
  var select = document.getElementById("paket");
  query += "?paket=" + select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  window.location.assign(query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your functions are resetting the URL.

What you can do is use `URLSearchParams` to generate the query string.

```
function jsFunction(params) {
    var myselect = document.getElementById("projektnamn");
    params.set('projektnamn', myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value);
}

function jsFunction2(params) {
    var select = document.getElementById("paket");
    params.set('paket', select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
}

const params = new URLSearchParams();
jsFunction(params);
jsFunction2(params);
window.location.href = `${location.pathname}?${params}`;
```

From what it looks like you are trying to build a single function, not two separate functions. I would replace these 2 functions with one generic.

```
function jsFunction(params, id, name) {
    var myselect = document.getElementById(id);
    params.set(name, myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value);
}

const params = new URLSearchParams();
jsFunction(params, "projektnamn", 'projektnamn');
jsFunction(params, "paket", 'paket');
window.location.href = `${location.pathname}?${params}`;
```

Comment: How do I add that to a 
```<select name="paket" id="paket" onChange="services()" class="form-control">```

Comment: @Hallberg You didn't have that detail in your question. I would advise to add event listeners in JavaScript instead of doing this on each HTML element's event. This would probably be a topic for a new question altogether.

Comment: Also how do you want this redirect to work? When you select one option it will redirect immediately. You have to write this logic in JavaScript.

Comment: I set up a new question instead, with every moment.

Comment: Solved it by using  ```window.location.href``` in the first one and the ```history.pushState``` in the second one with a ```window.location.search```